# How to update multiple entities atomically using Objectify transactions

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, objectify

I am using google-app-engine for my REST backend and google-datastore as the database. I am accessing datastore via objectify.

I have an API call where I want to update more than one entity (let's say 3 entities).

My requirement is that either all should be updated or none of them should be updated. I want this to be guaranteed in also possible scenarios including error cases where the instance running the code crashes/ goes down.

Even if I am doing all my updates inside a transaction, how is atomiticity ensured

```
ofy().save().entity(thing1);
ofy().save().entity(thing2);
ofy().save().entity(thing3);
```

Let's say all the above save() happenend inside a transaction, now if the instance running this code crashed after "thing1" is saved, I would have a case where 1 entity is updated and others or not which I want to avoid.

I looked at the objectify documentation on Transactions at: https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Transactions#basic-transactions but couldn't find any such examples or descriptions

I also looked at the datastore documentation at: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions

I have never used datastore directly so I am not very familiar with its APIs, but at the above link they have given an example of transferring funds from one account to another where from the description it looks like the updating of two entities is happening atomically (otherwise it would not handle the corner case where the instance running the code crashes after debiting amount from one account and before crediting it to the other). Is my understanding correct?

So basically my questions are:

1. Is there a way in objectify to update multiple entities atomically (which handles the corner case of the instance running the code crashing)? If yes then how?
2. If not then what are the alternatives?
3. Is it possible by directly using datastore APIs? Is that example provided in the link I shared above regarding transferring fund and example of atomic update? If I provide mulitple entities in the put() API of datastore - is it guaranteed in all scenarios (including instance crashing) that either all none of the updates happend?
4. There is an API is objectify to perform batch updates of entities:

   ofy().save().entities(entityList).now();

However as per my understanding , this API is not guaranteed to be atomic and therefore I can't use it for my case. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically **Objectify** allows you to access the Cloud Datastore functions. It means that in order to do what you want (atomic saves or updates), you have to update/save data within a transaction because (from [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/transactions)):

> A transaction is a set of Google Cloud Datastore operations on one or
>   more entities. **Each transaction is guaranteed to be atomic, which
>   means that transactions are never partially applied.** Either all of
>   the operations in the transaction are applied, or none of them are
>   applied.

1. Regarding your first question:

You should use the **transact method**, like in this [example](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Transactions):

```
import static com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService.ofy;
import com.googlecode.objectify.Work;

// If you don't need to return a value, you can use VoidWork
Thing th = ofy().transact(new Work<Thing>() {
    public Thing run() {
        Thing thing = ofy().load().key(thingKey).now();
        thing.modify();
        ofy().save().entity(thing);
        return thing;
    }
});
```

In the JavaDoc for the [Objectify interface](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.googlecode.objectify/objectify/5.1.21) it is stated that:

> You can run transactions by calling **Objectify.transact()** or
>   **Objectify.transactNew();**

2. Now your third question:

You can use the Datastore API, in [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/datastore-api-tutorial) there is an example of a transaction:

```
boolean markDone(long id) {
  Transaction transaction = datastore.newTransaction();
  try {
    Entity task = transaction.get(keyFactory.newKey(id));
    if (task != null) {
      transaction.put(Entity.newBuilder(task).set("done", true).build());
    }
    transaction.commit();
    return task != null;
  } finally {
    if (transaction.isActive()) {
      transaction.rollback();
    }
  }
}
```

3. Fourth question:

Just make sure you execute that line of code inside a transaction. Hope this helps

Comment: I had seen the objectify example you mentioned. But here only one entity is being saved. My question was when more than one entity is being saved. So if there are 3 calls to ofy().save().entity() in the transaction and after the first call, the instance running the code crashes - how will the save to the first entity be rolled back - and who will roll it back ? I suppose only way it will work is if during transaction all the saves are store in some temporary storage and after the transaction is done- it is pushed to datastore as a whole - but I didn't find any info like that anywhere

Comment: As far as I know, if one of the operations fails, none of the changes will take place. This is the definition of atomicity and this is what is stated in the docs. ... _A transaction is a set of Google Cloud Datastore operations on **one or more entities**_

Comment: Yes, I suppose what you are saying is correct. The only thing is if you look at objectify documentation on transactions at https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Transactions
It says _Transactions are where Objectify departs most significantly from the patterns set by the Low-Level API and JDO/JPA_. I am not sure if it changes to atomic nature of transaction, although I suppose atomicity is a basic feature of transactions and objectify should not change that, in that case what you are saying should be correct.

Comment: Atomicity is inherent in the definition of 'transaction'.